# CSS styles with google

Tags: html, css

Hey stack over flow I have been getting into styling my fire fox browser and have run into a bit of a bump. When I try and re-color my search bar there seems to be a border or something andcant find out what it is that's making that edge white if any one can help me it would be much appreciated.

here is the code I have put in at the moment

```
 input#gbqfif
 {
     color: #AADA2C !important;
     background: #262626;
     border: 0px;
 }
```

here is an image of what i'm going for and what is wrong

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTwo0.png

I hope you guys can help and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That thing, sir, is a div-beast:

[image: google search]

I found in my browser it's id = "gs_tti0" what you want to modify. So you should do:

```
#gs_tti0 {
  background-color: #262626;
  }
```

However, it looks like it might be dynamically generated. Just right click in the search bar, inspect element and change that background. If it doesn't work, go one level up (the parent). Keep doing so until you find the one you want.